# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Android crash related to okhttp and adobe analytics http connection

Tags: java, android, react-native, adobe-analytics

I have started seeing the following crash reported in Firebase Test Lab on numerous devices (this one on Pixel API 25) with our React Native app. This was not reported when I tested the app at the end of January and I have made no changes to any SDKs/packages in that time, although I notice that there was an update to com.adobe.marketing.mobile:sdk-core (1.6.0) in February. I have tried this version as well as rolling back to earlier versions and also adding the latest versions of okhttp and okio to my dependencies but the issue persists.

I also noticed that the release notes for android core 1.6.0 mentions a fix for:

> a crash which was caused by the exception thrown from the Android okhttp library

I wonder if this is the issue I am encountering but some combination of the dependencies I am using means I am not getting this fix.

FATAL EXCEPTION: ADBMobileBackgroundThread

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8192; index=8192
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.Buffer.writeByte(Buffer.java:973)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.concatLengthPrefixed(Platform.java:130)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.configureTlsExtensions(Platform.java:84)
    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:230)
    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199)
    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
    at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:329)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
    at com.adobe.marketing.mobile.HttpConnectionHandler.a()
    at com.adobe.marketing.mobile.AndroidNetworkService.c()
    at com.adobe.marketing.mobile.AndroidNetworkService.b()
    at com.adobe.marketing.mobile.AnalyticsHitsDatabase.l()
    at com.adobe.marketing.mobile.AnalyticsHitsDatabase.i()
    at com.adobe.marketing.mobile.AnalyticsHitsDatabase.a()
    at com.adobe.marketing.mobile.HitQueue$1.run()
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

app\build.gradle

```
    implementation 'com.adobe.marketing.mobile:analytics:1.+'
    implementation 'com.adobe.marketing.mobile:userprofile:1.+'
    implementation 'com.adobe.marketing.mobile:sdk-core:1.+'
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@adobe/react-native-acpanalytics": "^1.3.0",
    "@adobe/react-native-acpcore": "^1.5.0",
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Length of your array is 8192 and on other hand you are trying to pick data from 8192 index but you array has 0 to 8191 indexes. So 8192 index does not exists and your app gets crash

Comment: Thanks, Muhammad. That much I do understand however this is a crash in the Native Java code and not my React Native code, so I am looking for any known issues with the Native dependencies I am using, e.g. okhttp or adobe analytics SDK.

Comment: Probably best to avoid unpinned versions like 1.+, but that doesn't answer your question.